# Persisting shell functions or aliases defined by a sourced script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script -- in this example, named `myCommand.sh` -- which when sourced (with `. myCommand.sh`) defines a command named `sayit` in my local shell.

However, right now, when I run `. myCommand.sh`, the command `sayit` is defined only in the current terminal window.

How can I make this work even through terminal restarts without manual invocation?

Comment: Have you seen <http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84686/how-to-create-custom-commands-in-unix-linux> ?
There is a proper solution for your problem.

Comment: For example, I want to make a bash command named sayit to print out " Hello World".  When I execute .myCommand, it works,but just for the current terminal. Will not be working in a new terminal.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to use `chmod +x` to be able to run `. somescript` or `source something`; it's only needed for commands that are run as external processes, not sourced into the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that inside `myCommand.sh` you have the following:

```
sayit() { echo "Hello World"; }
```

...or the worse / more-fragile alternative:

```
alias sayit='echo "Hello World"'
```

...then you can make this permanent in two ways:

- Create a script named `sayit` that contains `echo "Hello World"`. This might look like the following:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  echo "Hello World"
  ```
- Add a command to source `myCommand.sh` to your dotfiles (ie. `~/.bashrc`). This would mean that you would be appending something like:

  ```
  . /path/to/myCommand.sh
  ```

  ...or its bash-specific equivalent:

  ```
  source /path/to/myCommand.sh
  ```

  ...to your `~/.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

`chmod +x` is a permanent operation. run with `./mycommand.sh`, or `/path/to/mycommand.sh`, or put the script in a folder which is in path, e.g. `~/bin/`

Comment: For example, I want to make a bash command named sayit to print out " Hello World". When I execute .myCommand, it works,but just for the current terminal. Will not be working in a new terminal.

Comment: "_put the script in a folder which is in path, e.g. ~/bin/_"

Comment: `. myCommand.sh` -- as the OP reports that they're doing -- is sourcing content into the active shell -- presumably the OP's commands are defined as shell functions, aliases, or similar. What you're suggesting here will only work if executing the script ran the desired commands directly, vs defining them in the active shell for later use.

Answer (score -1):

**. myCommand.sh** Will work only in current terminal only. put this script in some location and add same location in .bash_profile.

**example:** 
file : /home/myuser/.myCommand/myCommand.sh

Bash Profile Entry:
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH:**/home/.myCommand**:.